# OpenSSL - Convert X509* x509 to file-BIO* via memory

Tags: c++, openssl, x509certificate

I am working with a ".cer" certificate file and my task is to push it to stack `STACK_OF(X509_INFO) *sk;`

I have converted the ".cer" to `X509* ptr` and now the issue I'm facing is on **how to convert `X509* ptr` to `BIO* stackbio`** since the method I'm using needs `BIO*` as a parameter to push to the stack.

```
sk = PEM_X509_INFO_read_bio(BIO* stackbio, sk, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the first step would to be convert `X509*` to `BIO*`. The function to do that is: `int i2d_X509_bio(BIO *bp, X509 *x);`. According to the docs https://linux.die.net/man/3/d2i_x509:

> i2d_X509_bio() is similar to i2d_X509() except it writes the encoding
>   of the structure x to BIO bp and it returns 1 for success and 0 for
>   failure.

Once you've got the `BIO*` containing the encoded certificate, you should be able to just push it on the stack https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/STACK_API:

```
/* add value */
#define sk_BIO_insert(st, val, i)       SKM_sk_insert(BIO, (st), (val), (i))
```